# How to create a frame for imagePickerController...i mean a custom cameraView in IOS.Is there anyother way other than Overlay?

Tags: iphone, ios

The camera view in the pic.like that one,the image picker as its ter in the Pic

[image]

Comment: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/nbukit

Comment: Sorry there has been some error when i tried...anyways thanks for Help buddy...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are searching for: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html

With AVCaptureSessionManager you can create your very own camera view.

Comment: And one more Question can we use BURST mode(like in (D)SLR's ) in this AVCam??

Comment: Maybe you can use a timer to call your capture function again after a specific time interval.